# merge dataframes in r using values in the first dataframe and column names in the second one

Tags: r

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. In my real dataframes, I have indices, so I added them here in the reproducible example too.

```
object <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
color <- c("red", "green", "blue")
shape <- c("square", "circle", "square")

df1 <- data.frame(object, color, shape, row.names = NULL)
df1

            object color  shape
    1           x1   red square
    2           x2 green circle
    3           x3  blue square

param <- c("weight", "len", "volume")
x1 <- c("value", "value", "value")
x2 <- c("value", "value", "value")
x3 <- c("value", "value", "value")
x4 <- c("value", "value", "value")
x5 <- c("value", "value", "value")

df2 <- data.frame(param, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, row.names = NULL)
df2

     param    x1    x2    x3    x4    x5
  1 weight value value value value value
  2 len    value value value value value
  3 volume value value value value value
```

df1's object column has the same values and the df2's column names (except the param column). df2 has more X columns than the number of df1's rows. x1, x2, x3, ... orders do not match in two data frames. I need to combine two datasets matching x's and get something like this:

```
            x1     x2     x3
weight   value  value  value
len      value  value  value
volume   value  value  value
color      red  green   blue
shape   square circle square
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first dataset can be reshaped better with `data.table::transpose`, then bind the second dataset with `intersec`ting columns from 'df1new', and set the 'param' column to row names attribute with `column_to_rownames` (from `tibble`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1new <- data.table::transpose(df1, make.names = 'object', keep.names ='param') 
bind_rows(df2 %>%
       select(any_of(names(df1new))), df1new) %>%
       column_to_rownames('param')
```

-output

```
#            x1     x2     x3
#weight  value  value  value
#len     value  value  value
#volume  value  value  value
#color     red  green   blue
#shape  square circle square
```

Comment: Thank you! I am using your code for my real data. But bind_rows gives me an error Error: Can't combine `..1$TCGA-AF-2687` <double> and `..2$TCGA-AF-2687` <character>. "TCGA-AF-2687" are names(df1new) and names(df2), I checked their type and they both have character type. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @YuliaKentieva  Ok that is an error because of difference in column type.  Just convert one of the data columns to character class to make both data column type same

Comment: @YuliaKentieva can you show the `str(df1new)` and the `str(df2 %>%
       select(any_of(names(df1new))))`

Comment: I think `rbind` would still work as it coerces the column type to character (precedence) i.e. `rbind(df2 %>%
       select(any_of(names(df1new))), df1new)`

Comment: I changed using as.character and I am getting the same error

Comment: @YuliaKentieva Can you show the `str` of the datasets.  May be there are some columns in your real data having different types.  are you still getting error with `rbind` insteda of `bind_rows`

Comment: str(df1new)
'data.frame': 2 obs. of  358 variables:
 $ TCGA-AF-2687: chr  "Rectum" "LSC"
 $ TCGA-3L-AA1B: chr  "Cecum" "RSC"
 $ TCGA-4N-A93T: chr  "Ascending Colon" "RCS"
 $ TCGA-4T-AA8H: chr  "Descending Colon" "LSC"

str(expr %>%
+       select(any_of(names(df1new))))
'data.frame': 20531 obs. of  358 variables:
 $ TCGA-AF-2687: num  0 5.15 2.09 199.29 668.37 ...
 $ TCGA-3L-AA1B: num  0.517 18.085 15.764 144.4 774.662 ...
 $ TCGA-4N-A93T: num  0 4.43 4.28 142.66 1185.29 ...
 $ TCGA-4T-AA8H: num  0 9.9 11.3 143.2 888.3 ...

Comment: Have you tried `rbind(df2 %>%
       select(any_of(names(df1new))), df1new) %>%
       column_to_rownames('param')`

Comment: @YuliaKentieva can you please confirm the outcome of using `rbind` Or else we have to assign the type of the first data to second before `bind_rows`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `dcast` + `melt` like below

```
library(reshape2)
p <- dcast(melt(df1, id = "object", variable.name = "param"), param ~ object)
rbind(df2[names(p)], p)
```

which gives

```
   param     x1     x2     x3
1 weight  value  value  value
2    len  value  value  value
3 volume  value  value  value
4  color    red  green   blue
5  shape square circle square
```

Answer (score 2):

dplyr-only version requiring two steps (longer then wider) rather than a single data.table::transpose. Would love to know if it's possible in dplyr in one step

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'param', cols = -object) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = param, names_from = object) %>%
  bind_rows(df2, .) %>%
  select(c('param', df1$object))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

as.data.frame(t(df1[-1])) %>% 
  `names<-`(df1$object) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("param") %>%
  bind_rows(df2, .) %>% 
  select(where(~all(!is.na(.))))
```

**Output**

```
   param     x1     x2     x3
1 weight  value  value  value
2    len  value  value  value
3 volume  value  value  value
4  color    red  green   blue
5  shape square circle square
```